# Path stack in a Java recursive search

Tags: java, search, recursion

I wrote a simple Depth-First search algorithm, which works, but is failing to build the patch right. Im having a tough time trying to understand, why - so, basically, need your help, guys :)

Here is the code:

```
public void Search(String from, String to) {
  String depart = from;
  String destin = to;

  if ( (NoChildren(depart) == false) 
    && (!depart.equalsIgnoreCase(destin)) ) {
    while (!depart.equalsIgnoreCase(to)) {
      closeStack.push(depart);
      depart = getChildren(depart);
    }
  }
}

public boolean NoChildren(String from) {
  boolean noChildren = false;

  int counter = 0;

  for(int j = 0; j < Flights.size(); j++) {    
    FlightInfo flight = (FlightInfo)Flights.elementAt(j);
    if (flight.from().equalsIgnoreCase(from)) {
      counter++;
    }
  }

  if (counter == 0) {
    noChildren = true;
  }
  return noChildren;
}


public String getChildren(String from) {
  for(int j = 0; j < Flights.size(); j++) {
    FlightInfo flight = (FlightInfo)Flights.elementAt(j);
    if (flight.from().equalsIgnoreCase(from)) {
      openStack.push(flight.to().toString());
    }
  }
  return openStack.pop().toString();
}
```

I made it longer just for clearance, and planning to optimize it - just need to make it work properly first :))

Ok, the main problem is with that closeStack, which was meant to contain a path from start to finish - but now, it contains whatever the algorithm checked :-[

Thanx in advance!!

Comment: How is this a recursive search? You have no recursive functions.

Comment: Recursion *can* be simulated using stacks, as the OP is trying to do. However, it's all very confused.

Comment: @Carl: Yeah, there's no backtracking or anything going on here. It will plow through the `flight` objects until it finds one with no destination, then stop. Rescuing this code is a matter of rewriting it completely.

Comment: Why do you want a depth first search? Are you intentionally trying to find long journeys that eventually arrive at the destination rather than the journey with the fewest steps? How do you plan to handle potential loops?

Comment: Hmm, didn't even notice that. I'm sure he wants BFS.

Comment: OK, done. I implemented and posted a Breadth First Search for the shortest possible sequence of flights from one given airport to another. More comments there.

Answer (score 4):

Maxim, there are a whole bunch of errors in your code. It looks as if you had an idea for what you wanted to do, and then threw some code at it until *something* emerged and worked a bit, but there's no clear concept here and thus it's no wonder it's not really working.

The core of this program is the Flights collection (why is `Flights` uppercased?), and it's very possible to build a working route finder around it. I'm not sure whether it would help you more to give you some hints or to simply build the program for you.

---

**Update:** I've meanwhile found a flight schedule for a Polish airline (don't ask!) with 203 distinct routings that I can use to fill and test a flight connection structure. I'm going to start hacking and we'll see how it goes.

---

**Update:** Here's the code.

To be at all useful for your apparent purpose, it's probably not enough to just find a routing (i.e. an itinerary of airports visited); you probably want a list of flights taken to get there. Note, of course, that there may be multiple combinations of flights that have the same itinerary - this code just finds the first.

You may want to modify the algorithm to place a weight (= cost) on travel time, if you have those, so your passengers get not just the smallest number of legs (= hops from one airport to the next) but also the shortest combined travel time. This more general form of the algorithm would be called Dijkstra's Algorithm, and is also described in Wikipedia.

Interestingly enough, it seems that BFS is not really suited to a recursive solution. Like your original code, my code is essentially imperative with a few loops. Note that the correct "main" data structure for doing BFS is not a stack but a queue!

```
public class Maxim {

   /**
    * Create a Maxim instance and run a search on it.
    */
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      try {
         Maxim maxim = new Maxim();
         Route r = maxim.findRoute("FCO", "DNV"); // tests a single origin/destination pair
         if (r == null) {
            System.out.println("No route found");
         } else {
            System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(r.toArray()));
         }
      } catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }

   /**
    * A simple Flight. Contains a flight number and only a single leg.
    * number: Flight number
    * dep: Departure airport
    * arr: Arrival airport
    */
   class Flight {
      final String number, dep, arr;
      public Flight(String number, String departure, String arrival) {
         this.number = number; this.dep = departure; this.arr = arrival;
      }
      public String toString() {
         return "Flight [number=" + this.number + ", dep=" + this.dep + ", arr=" + this.arr + "]";
      }
   }

   /**
    * Airport: A city and a list of Flights originating from it.
    */
   class Airport {
      public final String city;
      public List<Flight> flights = new ArrayList<Flight>();
      public Airport(String city) {
         this.city = city;
      }
      public String toString() {
         return "Airport [city=" + this.city + ", flights=" + this.flights + "]";
      }
   }

   /**
    * Route: A list of flights that get a traveller from a given origin to a destination.
    */
   static class Route extends ArrayList<Flight> { }

   /**
    * Our known list of flights. It's not really needed after initialization.
    */
   private List<Flight> flights = new ArrayList<Flight>();

   /**
    * List of airports. These constitute the graph we search.
    */
   private Map<String, Airport> airports = new HashMap<String, Airport>();

   /**
    * Constructor. Constructs the "airports" graph from a list of "flights" read from a file.
    */
   public Maxim() throws Exception {
      // Read flights from file into list "flights".
      // The file contains strings like " 696KGDWAW" = flight number, departure airport, arrival airport
      BufferedReader flightReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/home/carl/XX.flights"));
      while (true) {
         String flt = flightReader.readLine();
         if (flt == null) break;
         flights.add(new Flight(flt.substring(0,4), flt.substring(4, 7), flt.substring(7, 10)));
      }
      flightReader.close();
      // Create a map of each airport to a list of Flights departing from it.
      // This is the graph we'll be doing BFS on.
      for (Flight flight : flights) {
         String from = flight.dep;
         if (!airports.containsKey(from)) {
            Airport port = new Airport(from);
            port.flights.add(flight);
            airports.put(from, port);
         } else {
            Airport port = airports.get(from);
            port.flights.add(flight);
         }
      }
   }

   /**
      Algorithm (from Wikipedia):
      1. Enqueue the root node.
      2. Dequeue a node and examine it.
         If the element sought is found in this node, quit the search and return a result.
         Otherwise enqueue any successors (the direct child nodes) that have not yet been discovered.
      3. If the queue is empty, every node on the graph has been examined – quit the search and return "not found".
      4. Repeat from Step 2.
    */
   public Route findRoute(String origin, String destination) {
      Queue<Airport> queue = new LinkedList<Airport>();
      Map<Airport, Flight> backtrack = new HashMap<Airport, Flight>();
      Airport oriApt = this.airports.get(origin);
      if (oriApt == null) return null; // origin airport not found - no solution
      queue.add(oriApt);
      while (!queue.isEmpty()) {
         Airport apt = queue.remove();
         if (apt == null) break;
         if (apt.city.equals(destination)) { // Made it to destination; create the route and return it
            Route toHere = new Route();
            while (apt != oriApt) {
               Flight flt = backtrack.get(apt);
               toHere.add(flt);
               apt = airports.get(flt.dep);
            }
            Collections.reverse(toHere);
            return toHere;
         }
         // enqueue all new airports reachable from this airport.
         // record the flight that got us there in backtrack.
         for (Flight flt: apt.flights) {
            Airport destApt = airports.get(flt.arr);
            if (backtrack.containsKey(destApt)) continue; // we've been to this destination before - ignore
            backtrack.put(destApt, flt);
            queue.add(destApt);
         }
      }
      // if we're here, we didn't find anything.
      return null;
   }

}
```

Comment: Awww, how come you get to have all the fun?

Comment: how can you make it return multiple routes? I've tested it but only returns one route

Comment: @Franklin, the algorithm I used is for finding the first shortest path. If you really want to enumerate different possible paths, this one won't do it, and I don't have one handy that will. If I did, that wouldn't have anything to do with the current question anyway, so I suggest you ask this as a new question.